# lxml.iterparse: Unused variable 'event' (unused-variable)

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, pylint, iterparse

It was used lxml.iterparse and the code was checked with Pylint.
I want to write the code without unused variable "event". How can I do this?

```
context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(xml))
for event, elem in context:
    print(elem.tag)
```

Comment: Please show a complete input XML document, together with a complete Python script. Also, explain what your _goal_is. Thanks. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It might help to use `for _, elem in context:` to indicate a "throwaway variable" (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/407651).

Comment: Btw, `print elem.tag` must be `print(elem.tag)` (question is tagged with "python-3.x").

Comment: @Elena, you should post an actual answer (and accept it) so that it is clear that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved by using `_` for throwaway variables (thanks mzjn).

```
context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(xml))
for _, elem in context:
    print(elem.tag)
```